# django to vercel deployment error "serverless function has crashed"

Tags: django, postgresql, vercel

I created a django application with a postgres database, im trying to deploy to vercel, by all indication on the browser the server is working correctly , vercel is also working correctly however I'm receiving the message "serverless function has crashed". help

ive checked the logs, crosschecked the details and database values and ensured it runs locally.